# gst-uninstalled breaking on audioconvert

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I've been battling with building gstreamer on my ubuntu 14.04 system.

I recently found out about the very promising-looking gst-uninstalled scripts as outlined here: http://arunraghavan.net/2014/07/quick-start-guide-to-gst-uninstalled-1-x/

Unfortunately I've run into a bit of a snag when the script attempts to build audioconvert:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2bedadba1c03c8223e5a

Looking at the actual gst-uninstalled script here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/scripts/gst-uninstalled
I see no switches for a "stable" version. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

__tim from #gstreamer pushed fix. Working.

Comment: you can either put some infos and mark your answer as correct or close the question .. maybe it would be nice to mention the git commit that fixed the issue..